# How do I take the group quotient GL(2,R)/O(2)?

Tags: group-theory

I am using the following representation of a $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$
a+x \mathbf{\hat{x}} +y \mathbf{\hat{y}} + \mathbf{\hat{x}} \mathbf{\hat{y}} b = \begin{bmatrix}a+x & -b +y  \\  b+y & a-x\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I pose $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$, then I have effectively reduced the group from $GL^+(2,R)$ to $SO^+(2,R)$.

$$
a + \mathbf{\hat{x}} \mathbf{\hat{y}} b = \begin{bmatrix}a & -b   \\  b & a\end{bmatrix}
$$

But posing to $0$ is not the same as taking the quotient. Can someone show me how to take the quotient $GL^+(2,R)/SO^+(2)$, using the explicit notation above?

Comment: By "taking the quotient" do you mean, say, exhibiting an explicit diffeomorphism ${\rm GL}_2\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$ whose fibers are precisely the right ${\rm SO}(2)$-cosets? Or else, what do you mean precisely?

Comment: What is $R$? ${}$

Comment: Quotient how?  As an orbit space?  (Can't be as a group as $SO(2)$ isn't normal.)

Comment: @Randall, my apologies, I am interested in the $SO^+(2)$ group. Its normal right?

Comment: Why do you say $SO(2)$? Do you also have $a^2+b^2=1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Without $a^2+b^2=1$, it would be $O(2)$, right?

Comment: Wrong. You need to learn lots of basics.

Comment: @Anon21  no, it is not.

Comment: @runway44 Exactly, that is what I mean. Can it map to $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$?